# Using SendRequestAsync function in TLSharp Library

Tags: c#, telegram

As I found, until now TLSharp library is the best library that encapsulate Telegram API methods implemented by C#.

Unfortunately many of the Telegram methods is not implementd in this library, but they simplified the way implementing these methods.
TLSharp documentation says:

You can call any method with help of SendRequestAsync function. For example, send user typing method:

```
  //Create request 
  var req = new TLRequestSetTyping()
  {
    action = new TLSendMessageTypingAction(),
    peer = peer
  };

  //run request, and deserialize response to Boolean
  return await SendRequestAsync<Boolean>(req);
```

Now I want to know how can we implement other Telegram API methods using SendRequestAsync function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure TLSharp does not cover your call with its numerous message types?
Try to search in [TLSharp sources](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/tree/master/TeleSharp.TL/TL/Messages) for already implemented message class. Look for files starting from 'TLRequest...', e.g. TLRequestDeleteHistory, TLRequestCreateChat, etc.

If method you need is actually missing, you can implement it in the same way as TLSharp does:

1. Check what fields should be sent in request. See [telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/methods) for reference.
2. Inherit your custom message from abstract class `TLMethod`.
3. Implement following properties and methods that are abstract in base class:

   - `public abstract int Constructor { get; }`
   - `public abstract void SerializeBody(BinaryWriter bw);`
   - `public abstract void DeserializeBody(BinaryReader br);`
   - `public abstract void deserializeResponse(BinaryReader stream);`

`Constructor` property should just return some uniq integer for the method.

`SerializeBody` should write fields from step 1 to `BinaryWriter`.

`DeserializeBody` should read them from `BinaryReader`.

`deserializeResponse` can just call `ObjectUtils.DeserializeObject()`:

```
public override void deserializeResponse(BinaryReader br)
{
    Response = (TLAbsUpdates)ObjectUtils.DeserializeObject(br);
}
```

You can make your implementation similar to existing TLSharp methods, e.g. [TLRequestForwardMessage](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/blob/master/TeleSharp.TL/TL/Messages/TLRequestForwardMessage.cs).

**Update:**

Here is the code for adding user to Telegram chat or channel:

```
await client.SendRequestAsync<TLAbsUpdates>(new TLRequestAddChatUser()
{
    //  Chat or channel ID
    chat_id = chatId,
    //  User ID to be added
    user_id = userId,
    //  Number of last messages to be forwarded
    fwd_limit = forwardLimit,
});
```

See Telegram API page for [messages.addChatUser](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.addChatUser) for details.

Comment: My desired method is implemented in messages directory, but is not implemented in TelegramClient.cs. so it is not usable in TelegramClient class. 
1- I did not understand how to implement fields of the request in calling the method.
2- What is relationship between a method and the integer number that its calling method returns.

Comment: What request do you want to send? I'll post example of the call.

Comment: I need implementation for channels.joinChannel

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your guide was very helpful. Now the main problem is that channel methods are not documented in Telegram API page. What can I do in such a problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, Telegram API does not cover all functionality, and also is poorly documented.
I didn't have to work with channel calls. If you really need it, I suggest reviewing other API for Telegram (Java, C++, ...) and checking whether they provide methods you need.
If all they don't then probably it's not covered by Telegram API at all. If they do, you can dig into the sources and check what the request is actually sent. Then you can follow steps from my answer.
Rather difficult path, agree.